# Contour line not meeting together

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, contour, gaussian, continuous

I have written the following code for a Gaussian copula contour. However, at the bottom left the it is discontinuous. What could be the reason and how can I get a continuous contour?

```
contour(xgrid,ygrid,Z,[4e-6,4e-6],'EdgeColor',[1 0 0],'LineWidth',2);
```

[image: current image]
[image: full image in full]

Comment: It's not possible to tell from this question how the lines should be connected together; is the straight line between the ends really a contour of `Z == 4e-6`? A MCVE doesn't need to include all the data shown, but values for `Z(1:10,1:10)` would probably enough to explain it.